# Amen iPhone beta app download by browser?

Tags: iphone, ios, browser, download

can someone tell me how Amen (getamen.com) can offer their iphone beta app as in-browser download? doesn't it need the device uuid and some certificates/profiles? maybe by testflight sdk?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I second the notion that it could bea an enterprise distribution; we've worked with clients who do this sort of things for a limited crowd (e.g. their employees only). Check out the following links which might help;

- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html
- http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Enterprise_Deployment_Guide.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Is it enterprise distribution? You don't need UDIDs for that. The enterprise provisioning profile is generated with the enterprise certificate and specific App IDs.

Chances are the closed beta is not using enterprise provisioning, UDIDs are being gathered, and they are using ordinary ad hoc OTA distribution. Anyone can do this, you just need a web server and a small amount of HTML. Xcode's Archive build can do almost all the work for you. Testflight works the same way and does not get around needing UDIDs, the value there (to me at least) is all the tester management and feedback.